# How to load properties file into Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to load a properties file into Java present on linux dir.
connection.properties:

```
hiveDriver=HiveDriver
hiveServer=ip-1-2-1-1.
hivePort=123
hiveUser=huser
hivePassword=etl123
gpDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
metaStoreUrl=metaurl
port=5432
metaUser=devusr
metaPassword=abcdefg
gpAnalyticsServer=1.2.3.4.5
gpUser=gpuser
gpPassword=09987665
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String propFile  = "/home/devuser/connection.properties";
    InputStream inputStream = StartCount.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFile);
    if(inputStream != null) {
        props.load(inputStream);
    }
    String hiveDriver           = props.getProperty("hiveDriver");
    String hiveServer           = props.getProperty("hiveServer");
    String hivePort             = props.getProperty("hivePort");
    String hiveUser             = props.getProperty("hiveUser");
    String hivePassword         = props.getProperty("hivePassword");
    String gpDriver             = props.getProperty("gpDriver");
    String hiveMetaStoreServer  = props.getProperty("hiveMetaStoreServer");
    String port                 = props.getProperty("port");
    String hiveMetaUser         = props.getProperty("hiveMetaUser");
    String hiveMetaPassword     = props.getProperty("hiveMetaPassword");
    String gpAnalyticsServer    = props.getProperty("gpAnalyticsServer");
    String gpUser               = props.getProperty("gpUser");
    String gpPassword           = props.getProperty("gpPassword");
    System.out.println(hiveDriver)      ;
    System.out.println(hiveServer);
    System.out.println(hivePort);
    System.out.println(hiveUser);
    System.out.println(hivePassword);
    System.out.println(gpDriver);
    System.out.println(hiveMetaStoreServer);
    System.out.println(port);
    System.out.println(hiveMetaUser);
    System.out.println(hiveMetaPassword);
    System.out.println(gpAnalyticsServer);
    System.out.println(gpUser);
    System.out.println(gpPassword); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am submitting the jar from the same place where "connection.properties" is saved.
When I run the code, I see `null` printing from the println statements. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I did in the code above ?

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` looks for a resource in the classpath, is the parent directory of `"/home/connection.properties"` in the classpath ?

Comment: Its "/home/devuser/connection.properties". I had it corrected. I should've checked it while posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(propFile);
```

Thats it...

Because

`StartCount.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFile) != propFile`

Comment: The compiler says: Cannot instantiate the type InputStream

Answer (score 0):

Using [NIO2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) you can load the file (if you have the read permissions) and convert it to [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) like:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/home/devuser/connection.properties");
InputStream str = Files.newInputStream(path);
```

Comment: Flies or Files ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the path, try to replace for this:

```
String propFile  = "./connection.properties";
```